# View Image Full Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, desktop

On occasion I need to look at an image at fullscreen so it doesn't have anything else around it to distract me. Is there a way to do that? I can't seem to find a way to do it with preview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use View -> Slideshow to do this in Preview

Comment: That was simple enough. Not sure why I didn't try that before.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can use QuickLook (spacebar) and click the FullScreen button :)

Comment: and then you can not change the picture! -1

Comment: @WebBrother blame Apple for the sh**y implementation of QuickLook :p

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to a folder with pictures
2. Press **Command + A** to select all pictures
3. Press **Option + Space bar** to view all images in full
   screen
4. Press **Arrow keys** to view next/previous picture

Note: Do NOT press Command + Backspace because It deletes all selected pictures!

Tested on macOS Big Sur 11.2

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌥␣</kbd> in Finder opens QuickLook directly in full screen. There's also Sequential, a small app basically meant for viewing folders of images in full screen.